# Add scale bar for plotting ppp object

Tags: r-sp, spatstat

I would like to add a scale bar to plots of spatstat objects but am not sure how.

Here is a reproducible example:

Plot ppp object called "cells":

```
data(cells)
plot(cells)
```

[image: cells]

How would I add a scale bar to this plot?

Comment: Please consider upvoting and/or accepting an answer if it solves your problem or explain what is missing.

Comment: thanks for the tip! i'm new to the site and didn't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just Googled 'spatstat scale bar' and the second hit was [the help file for yardstick()](https://rdrr.io/cran/spatstat/man/yardstick.html) while the top hit concerned the plot method for the yard stick. The title of the help file is "yardstick: Text, Arrow or Scale Bar in a Diagram". Maybe that is what you are looking for.

E.g:

```r
library(spatstat)
W <- union.owin(owin(c(0,1),c(0,5)), owin(c(0,5),c(4,5)))
X <- runifpoint(100, win = W)
plot(X, main = "")
y <- yardstick(3,1,4,1, txt = "1 unit")
plot(y, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-11-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. Yes, i did look into yardstick, but am not sure how to use it for my real data. The window in my real data is very narrow and as far as I understand, it seems that the yardstick will have to be placed at coordinates within the window itself, where there isn't really any free space. I am looking for a way to put a scale bar outside of the window.

Comment: The coordinates of the observation window follow the bounding box of the rectangle. See my update for an example where a stick is plotted outside the window, but inside the bounding box (frame).